# icCube Reporting AmChart balloon text fromatting

Tags: amcharts, iccube, iccube-reporting

Working with an amchart  bubble in iccube reporting, If I leave the default balloon behavior, I get [image]

Which is almost what I want...   I just want to replace x, y and value by their parameterized axis names... I then tried to put `<b>[[title]]</b></br>Evo @{AnneeRefSelected} - @{AnneeFinSelected} : [[x]]</br>PDM Séjours @{AnneeFinSelected} : [[y]]</br> <b>Séjours @{AnneeFinSelected} : [[value]]</b>` in widget's Graph.Balloon Text property instead... but then :

1. the formatting of numbers has gone
2. I loose the series name

[image]

Any help appreciated, Thxs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can use fValue to get a formatted version of the value column, the third in this case. Unfortunatly, there is no version for x and y (fX, fY). We will add this to future versions.

On the meantime as all value columns have a formatted version we can use this. Assuming that you have the following column labels: `column0`, `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, you have to add the following as balloon text:

```
<b>[[column0]]</b></br>Evo @{AnneeRefSelected} - @{AnneeFinSelected} : [[column1Formatted]]</br>PDM Séjours @{AnneeFinSelected} : [[column2Formatted]]</br> <b>Séjours @{AnneeFinSelected} : [[column3Formatted]]</b>
```

Here it is an example, the pivot table on the right side contains the underlying data of the Bubble chart:
[image]

Comment: Ok , I understand!   And the first one (Asia here) is the name of the hierarchy... Txs.